# Socket is not defined when I have created one

Tags: python, sockets, nameerror

I have a program that just sends messages to a server through a tkinter interface. I am using various subprograms to run basic things like starting a new connection and sending a message. The only issue is, it keeps on coming up with the name error "clientsocket is not defined" when the user *has* to go through another subprogram to establish the connection.

I have tried moving the subprograms around, making clientsocket a global variable and I have double-checked that my names are correct. The code I got these subprograms from functions fine (a chatting program that runs in the console that I made a while ago) so it must be how I have structured the program.

Here is all the subprograms that deal with sockets

```py
def send_msg(): # Sends a message to the server (called from tkinter button)
        try:
            Csend = field.get("1.0", "end-1c")
            Csend = str(Csend)
            clientsocket.send(Csend.encode())

            field.delete()
            field.insert(END, "")
        except error as err:
            Csend = field.get("1.0", "end-1c") # 1.0 - Line one, char zero
            print(f"Can't send message \"{Csend}\": Not connected to a server")
            print(err)

    def new_connection():
        # Tkinter code goes here
        def connect_server(): # Tries to connect to the server
            try: # This runs the first check, if there is an existing connection
                clientsocket.close()
            except:
                print("No existing connection")

            try: # Runs the second check, if it can connect using the info
                clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

                host = host_ent.get() # Gets STR of host IP
                port = port_ent.get() # Gets STR of port
                port = int(port) # Converts port to INT

                clientsocket.connect((host, port)) # Connects to the server
            except:
                print("Could not connect, incorrect inputs?")

    def disconnect_server():
        try:
            clientsocket.close()
        except:
            print("No existing connection")
```

All of these subprograms are called from tkinter menubars or buttons.

I am quite new to sockets, so if any of the code is beginner-tier then I am sorry.

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't define your socket global, only local in you function. you should add `global clientsocket` under the header of every function you use your clientsocket.

Comment: I thought I only needed to global my client socket variable on the first line of the program.